# Stuck on adding image url and normal url in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have been tinkering around with a code along and adding a few extra things in however I am stuck now as I am trying to use props for the images and the external link but I am not getting it come through. I will change some of the names once everything is working well. My code with the links is below

```
export const avengers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bruce Banner',
    username: 'Hulk',
    icon: 'https://www.superherodb.com/pictures2/portraits/10/050/83.jpg?v=1602236687',
    link: 'https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Hulk'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Steve Rogers',
    username: 'Cap',
    icon: 'https://www.superherodb.com/pictures2/portraits/10/050/274.jpg?v=1599853488',
    link: "https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clint Barton',
    username: 'Hawkeye',
    icon: 'https://www.superherodb.com/pictures2/portraits/10/050/73.jpg?v=1597500181',
    link: "https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Hawkeye"
  },
```

And where I am passing the props is here

```
import React from 'react';

const Hulk = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5">
      <img alt="avengers" className="photo" src={this.props.icon} />
      <div>
        <h2>{props.name}</h2>
        <p>{props.email}</p>
        <a href={this.props.link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          To learn more about {props.name}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hulk;
```

I am calling through Hulk component through the code below

```
import React from 'react';

const AvengersList = ({ avengers }) => {
    const avengersComponent = avengers.map((user, i) => {
        return (
        <Hulk
        key={i}
        id={avengers[i].id}
        name={avengers[i].name}
        email={avengers[i].email}
        />
    );
})

return (
 <div>
 {avengersComponent}
 </div>
);
}

export default AvengersList;
```

Comment: It entirely depends on how you're calling the `Hulk` component but If I had to guess I would say try: `src={props.icon}` instead of `src={this.props.icon}`

Answer (score 1):

"**this**" is only used in a **Class component** and not in a Functional component (and your component "Hulk" is a functional component!)

```
// Functional component :
import React from 'react'

export default function FunctionalComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}


// Class component :
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ClassComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

About your problem there are 2 cases:

1. You don't have a child component and you want to display the
   "Avengers" data.
2. You have a child component and you want to display the "Avengers"
   data inside this component.

---

**1st case:**

```
import React from "react";
    
// import your data
import avengers from "./data";

export default function Hulk() {
  return (
    <>
      {avengers.map(avenger => (
        <div
          key={avenger.id}
          className="tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5"
        >
          <img alt="avengers" className="photo" src={avenger.icon} />
          <div>
            <h2>{avenger.name}</h2>
            <p>{avenger.email}</p>
            <a href={avenger.link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
              To learn more about {avenger.name}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

- You need to use a .map() to display your data
- You don't need to use "props" because in this case you haven't child component.

Demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ucgx4n?file=src%2FHulk.js)

---

**2nd case:**

Parent component (who sends the props):

```
import React from "react";

// import your data
import avengers from "./data";

// import your child component
import DetailsCpt from "./DetailsCpt";

export default function Hulk() {
  return (
    <>
      {avengers.map(avenger => (
        <div
          key={avenger.id}
          className="tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5"
        >
          <img alt="avengers" className="photo" src={avenger.icon} />
          <DetailsCpt props={avenger} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Child component (Who receives the props):

```
import React from "react";

export default function DetailsCpt({ props }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <p>{props.email}</p>
      <a href={props.link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        To learn more about {props.name}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- You need to use a .map() in parent component to display the data in both components: directly in parent component and with **props in child component**.

Demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-swpcc2?file=src%2FHulk.js)